# Error while searching in Sitecore CMS Could not find File Indexes\Sitecore_mastes_index\Segmnet_1ac

Tags: content-search

While searching through path or ID in CMS, i get the following error

> Could not find File \Indexes\Sitecore_mastes_index\Segment_1ac

https://www.screencast.com/t/DkeqUjPlc

Comment: Make sure that related indexes (Lucene) and cores (SOLR) are available for your Sitecors instance. In this case sitecore_mastes_index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your master index is corrupted.

If you cannot delete the folder please restart application pool (w3p process)

Please go to the E:\Finaal\823\Data\Indexes and delete all the files from the master index folder (sitecore_master_index).

Go to Control Panel-> Indexing Manager and rebuild sitecore_master_index

[image]